# Get top 3 most occuring numbers in a List

Tags: c#, list, linq

Let's say I have a List of ints.
I add some values:

```
list.Add(5);

list.Add(5);

list.Add(27);

list.Add(3);

list.Add(4);

list.Add(4);

list.Add(29);

list.Add(3);
```

How do I get the **3** most **occurring numbers**? Like this: 5, 3 and 4.

I've tried :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Mode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    var dict = input.ToLookup(x => x);
    if (dict.Count == 0)
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    var maxCount = dict.Max(x => x.Count());
    return dict.Where(x => x.Count() == maxCount).Select(x => x.Key);
}
```

But it is only returning me one number.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The solutions below all involve sorting the collection. If you want an O(N) solution (more efficient than an O(N log(N)) sort, the dedicate three integer variables to hold your top three numbers and iterate over the collection, comparing the current value to those three.

Comment: @Flydog57 That works if you want the 3 largest numbers.  But in this case you have to keep track of the number of occurrences of the number, so you'd need to have 3 variables for that as well along with a dictionary to hold the current counts of all seen numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine

```
var topThreeMostOccuring = arr.GroupBy(x => x)
.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
.SelectMany(x => x.Take(1)).Take(3);
```

Comment: `SelectMany` is used to flaten enumerable of enumerables

Comment: You could just do `Select(x => x.Key)` instead of the `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq :

```
var top3 = list.GroupBy(x => x)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
               .Take(3)
               .Select(x => x.Key);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", top3)); // output 5 3 4
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. Your solution worked great. My label wasn't big enough to display all the numbers... **Dumb me**. Thanks again!

Comment: This is the better way to do it btw.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
 var list = new List<int>();

        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(27);
        list.Add(4);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(4);
        list.Add(4);
        list.Add(29);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(4);



       var TheMostoccurring =  list.GroupBy(n => n).OrderByDescending(m => m.Count()).Select(m => m.Key).ToList().Take(3);



        foreach (var item in TheMostoccurring)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Comment: @juharr I am sorry that is my mistake the ToList() not needed